# Chrome Extension: chrome.tabs.executeScript result from file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm using `chrome.tabs.executeScript` for when I am iterating through tabs in the current window. I am trying to get the results from the file `storeTabFavicon.js`.

I read that the callback function would have an array of results from each tab, but it is returning `undefined`. For example, if I had two tabs open, the console would show:

## console

```
result[0]: null
result[0]: null
```

## background.js

```
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true}, function(tabs)
{
    var tabFavicon= [];
    var tabCount = 0;

    for (; tabCount < tabs.length; tabCount++)
    {
        tabFavicon[tabCount] = storeTab(tabs, tabCount);
    }
})

function storeTab(tabs, tabCount)
{
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[tabCount].id, {file: "storeTabFavicon.js"}, function (result)
    {
        console.log("result[0]: " + result[0]);
    })
}
```

## storeTabFavicon.js

```
var currentFaviconURL = document.querySelector("link[rel*='shortcut icon']").href;
if (currentFaviconURL)
{
    return "yes";
}
else
{
    return "no";
}
```

## manifest.js

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Extension",
    "version": "0.1",

    "browser_action":
    {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "background":
    {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "content_scripts":
    [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["content.js"]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": ["tabs", "storage", "*://*/*"],
}
```

Comment: Functions that accept callbacks in the extension API don't return anything themselves. You need to rework your code as shown in [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](//stackoverflow.com/q/14220321) - the simplest approach is probably async/await.

Comment: BTW  `var tabFavicon = tabs.map(t => t.favIconUrl)` is all you need here AFAICT.